# Why are there different blood sugar measurements?

Tags: blood-tests, glucose, blood-sugar

I've been reading about health and wondering why blood sugar measurements are different. Why do these different sites use different measurements and give different numbers?

Examples:

[Less than 100](https://about.usps.com/postal-bulletin/2016/pb22435/html/images/info_002_1.jpg)
[image]

[36-48mmol/mol or 5.5-6.8%](https://dpcindiana.com/do-you-know-your-numbers/)
[image]

[5.6% or less](https://www.nationaljewish.org/NJH/media/img/Health%20Insights/Infographics/Love-Your-Numbers_888.jpg)
[image]